# PHP DateTime() date issue

Tags: php

```
$now = new DateTime();
print_r($now);
print $now->date; // print the current date
```

BUT if print_r($now); is comment it show error ?

```
$now = new DateTime();
print $now->date; // Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in
```

Comment: There is no `date` defined in the member functions/attributes [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Please do not use undocumented properties or bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property in this class. Use format function instead:

```
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382) (I 'm not sure exactly which versions are affected).

Class [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) does **not** have a `date` property, but calling `print_r` on it creates a "hidden" property that looks like it's there (it is displayed with `print_r`) but in reality is not (you cannot get its value).

Instead of this, use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get the date value in whatever format you want.

Comment: @downvoter: Did you test this yourself? Because I know for a fact I am correct.

Comment: Hmm, this is correct ... but it's also a dupe I believe :)

Comment: @Jack: Ya, I found the dupe and bug, CVed and linked. But sheesh.

Comment: I did know it was not possible to access the 'date' property, but I didn't know it was a bug. +1

Comment: @Benz Derick Rethans will tell you that it's by design ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to print the date using the `DateTime` object, use the following method:

```
$Date = new DateTime();
$Date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

The following page can help you format the output:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php